# Limit bokeh plot pan to defined range

Tags: python, bokeh

I was wondering if it were possible to limit the range of the "pan" tool for bokeh generated plots? For example, say I had this simple plot:

```
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, rect, show
output_file('test.html')
rect([10,20,30], [10,20,30], width=[1,2,3], color=['red','blue','green'], height=5, plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools = "ypan,box_zoom,reset")
show()
```

The ypan tool works great, but I could keep panning until my graph disappears. Is there any way I can constrain the pan?

Answer (score 10):

The pan/zoom limit feature has been added after this question was first posed.

You can feed the `y_range` or `x_range` keyword arguments on a bokeh model a `Range1d` object with the keyword argument `bounds` set to a tuple to limit the pan boundaries.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Range1d

fig = figure(y_range=Range1d(bounds=(0, 1)),
             x_range=Range1d(bounds=(0, 1)))
```

Note that the `Range1d`'s first two positional arguments are for setting the default view-port for an axis, and the bounds is independent of those arguments.

---

If you want your bounds to be limited by the range values, then you can pass  bounds `auto`:

```
Range1d(0, 1, bounds="auto")
```

Comment: How do you do this for a list of strings instead of a range like 0>1

Comment: @azazelspeaks Haha, whoops